# Window function (LEAD/LAG) with where clause?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a table of page hits on a website and for each page of a specific type (`marketing_page`), I am trying to identify the next page a customer hits. So my query would probably look something like this

```
Select * from 
(
Select page_id
, hit_time
, customer_id
, session_id
, page_type
, LEAD(page_id, 1) over (PARTITION BY customer_id, session_id ORDER BY hit_time) as next_page_id
FROM page_hits
)
WHERE page_type = 'marketing_page'
```

The problem with this approach is that the sub-query becomes HUGE if I keep the `WHERE` clause outside the sub-query. Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
Select page_id
, hit_time
, customer_id
, session_id
, page_type
, LEAD(page_id, 1) over (PARTITION BY customer_id, session_id ORDER BY hit_time) as next_page_id
FROM page_hits
WHERE page_type = 'marketing_page'
```

but have it still account for pages outside the `WHERE` clause when doing the `LEAD` function. I understand that the `LEAD` function gets evaluated after the `WHERE` so this is not possible.

I would also like to avoid a self join because of the efficiency issue. Is there a fast/simple way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having a specific performance issue?  SQL is a *declarative* language, so the subquery may not be completed evaluated "before" the where is processed.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. It times out before being able to evaluate the sub query.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Redshift?  They are very different databases (even if once upon a time the code bases were similar).

Comment: sorry should've clarified, using redshift

Comment: The derived table has no performance impact whatsoever, in this case it's simply syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

If a simple `lead()` does not work on a Redshift table, that could mean one of several things.  What come to mind are:

- The Redshift databases is busy, having used up all query connections and you are just waiting.  I'll assume this is not the case.
- Your data is seriously big.
- Your "table" is really a complicated view.

Given the nature of the data, I would assume that the data is seriously big.  I would further assume that it is partitioned by some time unit, probably day.

You need to limit the query to one or a handful of partitions to run it.  Your question provides no information on how that might be done.

Comment: The data is seriously big. Table is partitioned on days and I hoping to get a year at a time but have also tried 6 months.

Comment: @doddy . . . Probably any query on the data -- without limiting partitions -- is going to time out.  The issue may not be the window function.